# How to add a Tooltip to a "td" with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I need to add a tooltip/alt to a "td" element inside of my tables with jquery.

Can someone help me out?

I tried:

```
var tTip ="Hello world";
$(this).attr("onmouseover", tip(tTip));
```

where I have verified that I am using the "td" as "this".

**Edit:**I am able to capture the "td" element through using the "alert" command and it worked.  So for some reason the "tip" function doesn't work.  Anyone know why this would be?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you might want to have a look at http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

Answer (score 25):

```
$(this).mouseover(function() {
    tip(tTip);
});
```

a better way might be to put `title` attributes in your HTML. That way, if someone has javascript turned off, they'll still get a tool tip (albeit not as pretty/flexible as you can do with jQuery).

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td title="Tip 1">Cell 1</td>
            <td title="Tip 2">Cell 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and then use this code:

```
$('#myTable td[title]')
    .hover(function() {
        showTooltip($(this));
    }, function() {
        hideTooltip();
    })
;

function showTooltip($el) {
    // insert code here to position your tooltip element (which i'll call $tip)
    $tip.html($el.attr('title'));
}
function hideTooltip() {
    $tip.hide();
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate? what DOES happen? are there any error messages? have you actually got a function called "tip"?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#grdList tr td:nth-child(5)').each(function(i) {
    if (i > 0) { //skip header
        var sContent = $(this).text();
        $(this).attr("title", $(this).html());
        if (sContent.length > 20) {
            $(this).text(sContent.substring(0,20) + '...');
        }
    }
});
```

grdList - table id

td:nth-child(5) - column 5

Comment: This helped me a lot, however it makes more sense to use `$(this).text()` for the title instead of `$(this).html()`, esp. if you have hyperlinks in your cells.

Answer (score 1):

```
var tTip ="Hello world";
$(this).mouseover( function() { tip(tTip); });
```

Answer (score 1):

## grdList - table id

td:nth-child(5) - column

```
$('#grdList tr td:nth-child(5)').each(function(i) {
    if (i > 0) { //skip header
        var sContent = $(this).text();
        $(this).attr("title", $(this).html());
        if (sContent.length > 20) {
            $(this).text(sContent.substring(0,20) + '...');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you really do want to put those tooltips on your table cells and not your table headers--where they'd make much more sense--please consider putting them on the content INSIDE the table cells, where it's much more meaningful.