# how to show tooltip on cell hover using jquery

Tags: jquery

[see in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2sjaZ/12/)
On mouse hover of cell i have to show Name in tooltip using jquery

like this
John
Fixed

```
 <td class="csstdRed" valign="top"><span id=32>John</span></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited your JFiddle code.  Here is what I added

```
$('#tableAppointment td[title]')
    .hover(function() {
        showTooltip($(this));
    }, function() {
        hideTooltip();
    })
;

function showTooltip($el) {
    // insert code here to position your tooltip element (which i'll call $tip)
    $tip.html($el.attr('title'));
}
function hideTooltip() {
    $tip.hide();
}
```

Then added Title to the td

```
<td class="csstdRed" title="John Fixed" valign="top"><span id=32>John</span></td>
```

Hope this will help you.  I got this idea from [How to add a Tooltip to a "td" with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165650/how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-a-td-with-jquery)  I guess this is what you wanted.

Thanks..

Comment: Dilip john text which is inside span not in title in my quetion

Comment: Do you want display the span as tooltip ah?

Comment: Ok I got it.. let me check and tell you after some time.